# Typeorm MINUS operator

Tags: sql, typeorm

I'm trying to do a set difference in SQL.  I've discovered the MINUS operator, which seems to do exactly what I need: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-minus-operator/

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use this operator via typeorm.  I'm currently using `connection.getRepository().createQueryBuilder()`, and I don't see any methods on the resulting query builder that look like they correspond to the MINUS operator.

Extra context on what I'm trying to do:
I have a Request table/entity, and each request has a field that specifies an internal resource that the request is related to, let's call it `target_id`.  I want to find all the Requests older than 1 month, but only where there are no **other** requests on the same `target_id` that are newer than 1 month.

EDIT:
Actually, thinking about this more, I'm not even sure the MINUS operator does exactly what I want either.  I could write something like
`SELECT * from request WHERE request.updated_at < :deadline MINUS SELECT * from request WHERE request.updated_at > :deadline`, but the problem is that that's always just going to return the result of the first SELECT since there will never be any exact overlap between the two result sets.  What's missing is a way to compare the two result sets and find the ones that share a `target_id` and remove the results from the first set that share a `target_id` with any results in the second set.  I assume there's probably some way to do this with a JOIN of some kind, but it's beyond my abilities with SQL.  Any guidance here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please read this and edit your question to include a concrete example : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-I-provide-a-Minimal-Reproducible-Example-for-a-very-simple-SQL-query)

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE request.updated_at < :deadline AND target_id NOT IN (SELECT target_id from request WHERE requeted.updated_at > :deadline)`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks @DemiPixel!!!

Comment: @DemiPixel, if you add your comment as a proper answer to the question, I'll accept it as the answer and close this issue.  That way you get full credit for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeorm doesn't seem to support MINUS directly, but you can achieve the same effect in this case by using a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM request
WHERE request.updated_at < :deadline
    AND target_id NOT IN (
        SELECT target_id
        FROM request
        WHERE requeted.updated_at > :deadline
    )
```